# How to force refresh the image using Glide?

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I am using Glide library for displaying images.I set diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.Source) so the images are not clearing.When i update profile pic the image is not updated until i clear the instance of the app(I am clearing Glide.clearDiskCache and Glide.clearMemory()).So how to force refresh the image without clearing the instance .Please see the below code for better understanding

```
    if(!getBoolValueForProfilePicUploading())
    {        glide.with(context).load(imgData.url).asBitmap().centerCrop().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).placeholder(R.drawable.default_profilepic).error(R.drawable.default_profilepic).into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(userImageView) {
                    @Override
                    protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                        RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                                RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), resource);
                        circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                        userImageView.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
                    }
                });
            }else
            {
                new LongOperation(context,imgData,userImageView).execute();
            }
```

This is for asynctask background(),

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try
                {
                    Glide.get(context).clearDiskCache();
                    Glide.get(context).clearMemory();
                }catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }
```

Comment: have you tried `skipMemoryCache()` ?

Comment: no.Thanks for the reply .I will check and get back to u.

Comment: what is the class name for the method

Comment: yes I will try that one.

Comment: Try calling it like `Glide.with(mContext).load(url).skipMemoryCache(true).into(iv)`

Comment: I already used that one. I have static method to load the images. When I call the method for first time it is updating and again call the method it is displaying old image.

Comment: Ok. then try using both `skipMemoryCache(true)` & `diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)` in the same image request

Comment: thanks for ur reply i already used that one too. So how to declare glide context globally

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106906/discussion-between-much-overflow-and-mohan-raj).

Comment: @Ajay got the solution??

Answer (score 1):

I have tried

```
avatar.setImageURI(null);
avatar.setImageURI(avatarUri);
```

but `skipMemoryCache()` saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce "signature" to produze a unique key in order to invalidate cache. Call like this:

```
Glide.with(this)
    .load(uri)
    .signature(ObjectKey(file.lastModified()))
    .error(0)
    .into(binding.imagePreview)
```